# Calculation of time differences on client-side

Tags: javascript, http, time, elapsedtime

I have an application that displays a list of tasks on the UI. Along with their elapsed times. The elapsed time is the difference between the current time and the task's start time. I cannot make these calculations on the server side. And I cannot trust the client side to be in sync with the server time. The client side is aware of the task's start time, but the unknown here is the current time. From what I could think, I have two options:

1. Add a custom header, "ServerTimeInMilliseconds" to the response header. The client-side picks this up and calculates the difference.
2. Add a new end-point that provides the server's time in milli.

I understand that things like network latency can play a role, but that's acceptable.

I'm not sure how these situations are usually handled. Is there any other elegant easy way to handle these?

Edit: I failed to mention that the application is internal and might or might not have internet connection.

Comment: Does your client aware about geo-location of its server?

Answer (score 0):

The best accurate way to do this is let you client know about your server geo location. So we can fetch the current time by using the timezone of  your server.

If you can't get the exact timezone of your server, you can use following APIs to fetch it by geo location.

[Google Maps Time Zone](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/timezone/start)
[Microsoft Azure Maps Time Zone](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/maps/timezone)

You can get the current time by passing the timezone to [moment timezone](https://momentjs.com/timezone/) like this.

```
const currentTime = moment().tz(timezone).format();
```

This [article](http://www.javascriptkit.com/dhtmltutors/local-time-google-time-zone-api.shtml) might help you.

Comment: Won't it be much simpler if the server itself provides a time? The client might or might not  have access to the internet, since the application is run on intranet. Your solution depends heavily on the client side to fetch the timezone (API on the internet) and could therefor be unreliable.

Comment: You should add that condition to your question. Then you have get the time from the server. Use web sockets if possible.